# Overlay into empty line truncates line, workarounds?

Tags: overlays

I am using the `ov` library to display overlays.

If I try to insert an overlay into an empty line, it truncates the line. See the pictures below to understand the problem, and use the code to reproduce it.

(`ov.el` is just a wrapper using emacs' overlays, so this should not be a library specific problem.)

[image]
[image]

```
(require 'ov)
(defun untitled--display-char-at-point (char point)
  (progn (ov-set (ov point (+ 1 point))
                 'display char)))

(point)
(untitled--display-char-at-point "t" 192)

;; This line moves!
```

The below is another example of the same happening. If you evaluate this:

```
(defun untitled--display-char-at-point (char point)
  (progn (ov-set (ov point (+ 1 point))
                 'display char)))

(point)
(untitled--display-char-at-point "t" 184)
;; hi

;; This line moves!
```

you end up with this:

```
(defun untitled--display-char-at-point (char point)
  (progn (ov-set (ov point (+ 1 point))
                 'display char)))

(point)
(untitled--display-char-at-point "t" 184)
;; hi
t;; This line moves!
```

`GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.3.0, Carbon Version 157 AppKit 1347.57)`

Ps. could we get an `ov` tag? That library is the rural jurors bees' knees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question has nothing to do with `spacemacs`, so the reference to that library/configuration should be removed from the question so as not to confuse other forum participants.

The original poster should use a test to determine whether point -- **where the overlay will be placed** -- is at the end of the line, and use either of the following if that is the case:

- The `'display` property with the string plus a new-line `\n` -- e.g., `"t\n"`
- The `'after-string` property with just the string -- e.g., `"t"`

A sample test is as follows:  `(= (point) (point-at-eol))`

When `point` is not at the end of the line, just the string and the `'display` property will suffice.

Here are two examples of overlay placement when `point` is at the end of the line:

```
(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (1+ (point)) 'display "t\n")

(overlay-put (make-overlay (point) (point)) 'after-string "t")
```

Comment: Will try this out. I realise now that I did not make the question general enough for posterity; an overlay might be more than one point, this will surely complicate the workaround? E.g. overlay from 10-20 while eol is at 15...

Comment: @24HrRevengeTherapist: you have to decide whether you want the overlay to *replace* or *add* to the existing text, the existing text may or may not contain newlines, but there is nothing special about newlines per se.

Comment: @24HrRevengeTherapist -- if you have text spanning multiple lines, then you may need to create multiple overlays in order to handle an `eol` situation.  An alternative might be to use a `'face` property and then just colorize the region desired.